# Show $(V,\varphi \circ f )$ is an atlas of $S$

Tags: differential-geometry

> Let $U,V$ be open sets of $\mathbb{R^2}$ and $f:V \rightarrow U$ a diffeomorphism between them. Let $S$ be a regular surface and $(U, \varphi)$ an atlas of $S$. Show $(V,\varphi \circ f )$ is also an atlas of $S$.

Let $p\in S$. We have to show there exists an open subset $W \subset S$ such that $p \in W$ verifying:

- $\varphi \circ f: V \rightarrow W$ is an homeomorphism.
- $d(\varphi \circ f)_q : \mathbb{R^2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R^3}$ is injective $\forall q \in V$.

$(U, \varphi)$ is an atlas so there exists $W' \subset S$ with $p \in W'$ such that $\varphi:U \rightarrow W'$ is homeomorphic and $d(\varphi)_q$ is injective $\forall q \in U$.

If we take $W=W'$ then $\varphi \circ f: V \rightarrow W'$ is an composition of homeomorphisms and hence homeomorphism, but I don't know how to prove the injectivity of  $d(\varphi \circ f)_q$.

Comment: $d(\phi \circ f) = d\phi \circ df$. These are both injective because $f$ and $\phi$ are both diffeomorphisms. So, their composition is injective.

Comment: @OsamaGhani I don't see why the differential of a diffeomorphism has to be injective

Comment: By definition really. The derivative of a diffeomorphism is always an isomorphism of vector spaces. To see this, let $f: M\to N$ be a diffeomorphism and let $f^{-1}:N\to M$ be its inverse. Consider $d(f \circ f^{-1}) = id$ and $d(f^{-1} \circ f) = id$ and what that tells you about $df$ and $df^{-1}$. If it’s still not clear, let me know and I’ll write it up as an answer!

Comment: Thanks! Write it as an answer if you want to so I can accept it.